# The necessity of using Past Perfect when writing about past events

Tags: grammar

If, for example, I write that some territory belonged to some country until 1954, should I use Past Perfect ('had belonged')? Is it optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **past perfect tense** when you are describing a series of events in the past. For example, if you consider describing what happened after 1954, then you must use past perfect tense, provided you are speaking about/related to the same concept or story-line.

> The territory **had belonged** to the Empire until 1954, after which it went into the hands of the barbarians.

If you wish to depict/describe only a single event in the past, then you must consider using **simple past tense**.

> The territory **belonged** to the Empire until 1954.

For more reference and examples, you can read [this article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/).

Comment: Whether it's one or two separate sentences doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can have two to three sentences one after the other, but in the same paragraph while writing a story or developing script.

Comment: Is it obligatory? You used the word 'should'

Comment: Well, if you look at it that way, it is not an obligation, more like a suggestion, a good one at that. I should probably change the modal verb from "should" to "could".

Comment: Actually it is more of a grammatical sense than obligatory statement. Hence I think it would be highly confusing for fellow users to understand the concept if I replace _should_ with _could_. Then most of the people will not adapt the correct usage. Hence I shall keep it the same.